# Unable to get Azure AD OpenID Authentication Exchange mail field as a claim

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid

Our emails are different from UPNs.

To check and make sure I have the mail property, I connect via PowerShell to Azure AD and run the following command.

```
Get-AzureADUser -objectid upn@domain.com | Select-Object Mail

Mail                
----                
useremail@domain.com
```

So, in Azure AD I create a new Application Registration. In the app manifest, I enable `"acceptMappedClaims": true,`.

Then in Visual Studio I create an *ASP.NET Web Application* and select *Work or School Accounts* for authentication, point to my cloud domain and after it's created, update `ClientId` to point to the application registration, etc.

I then add a mapping policy:

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"ClaimsMappingPolicy":{"Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", "ClaimsSchema": [{"Source":"user","ID":"mail","JwtClaimType":"email"}]}}') -DisplayName "CustomClaims" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"
```

I then add the policy to the app via PowerShell:

```
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id [Enterprise Application Object Id] -RefObjectId [policy id]
```

In `Startup.Auth.cs` I add `Scope` list to include `email`

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        Scope = "openid profile email roles"
    });
```

Nothing seems to work. I am definitely missing some configuration step here...

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Not really. As a work around it turns out I can get the user’s alternate email field from Azure AD. That’s the field they fill out when they log into up their account for the first time. Since we sync our on-prem AD to Azure, I have a nightly task that pushes the Exchange email address that I can read locally into their Azure alternate email field. I then did manage to add that field as a custom login claim. End result is I can get user’s name, Sam account is and email when they login, as claims without any other calls back to Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure team has begun work on the V2 endpoint to support the email scope for id tokens. It can be provided on the V1 endpoint (or in V2 endpoint access tokens) via the optional claim ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims )

Comment: My question is about custom claims, though. I've found two ways described to add custom claims and was successful in adding "otherMail" field as a custom claim, but not the "mail" field. I've posted this question on MS support forums and have an Azure team trouble ticket in and in two weeks have been referred to the same two articles 3 times. It seems no one at Microsoft is able to actually produce a code sample that works though.